# R - cannot use variable generated by for loop as argument in table()

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract prop.test p-values over a set of columns in a dataframe existing in the global environment (df) and save them as a dataframe. I have a criteria column and 19 variable columns (among others)

```
proportiontest <- function() {
  prop_df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:19) {
    x <- paste("df$var_", i, sep="")
    y <- (prop.test(table(df$criteria, x), correct=FALSE))$p.value
    z <- cbind (x, y)
    prop_df <- rbind(prop_df, z)
  }
  assign("prop_df",prop_df,envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
proportiontest()
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
Error in table(df$criteria, x) : all arguments must have the same length
```

When I manually insert the column name into the function (instead of x) everything runs fine. e.g.

```
y <- (prop.test(table(df$criteria, df$var_1), correct=FALSE))$p.value
```

I seem to have the problem of using the variable (x) value generated via the for loop as the argument.

What am I missing or doing wrong in this case? I have tried passing x into the table() function as.String(x) as.character(x) among countless others to no avail. I cannot seem to understand in which form the argument must be. I'm probably misunderstanding something very basic in R but it's driving me insane and I cannot seem to formulate the question in a manner where google/SO can help me.

Comment: check the value of x. As it is defined it is a string. (apart from this, you probably should rethink the way you're doing the whole thing...)

Comment: You are doing absolutely everything wrong here. Using `assign`, growing objects in a loop, trashing your global environment with multiple data sets, etc. , etc. You should rethink why do you think you need to this and how you want to approach this.

Comment: For instance, assuming `criteria` is the first column in `df` (for simplicity), try `data.frame(P_vals = sapply(df[-1], function(x) prop.test(table(df$criteria, x), correct=FALSE)$p.value))`

Comment: Thank you very much! I must say I'm very much a beginner with R (and programming in general for that matter) and was just trying to approach things logically instead of "the R-way". In any case your example worked perfectly and I'll definitely try to approach these kind of things differently in the future. You would kill a kitten if you'd see my script file, but at least I can get my answers! Thanks again'

Answer (score 0):

Currently in your function x is just a string. If you want to use a column from your data frame df you can do this in your for loop:

```
x <- df[,i]
```

You'll then need to change z or you'll be cbinding a column to a single p value, maybe just change to this:

```
z <- cbind(i,y)
```

so that you know which df column belongs to each p value.

You should be careful as well since the function will search for df created within itself and then move to the parent environment if it doesn't find it, so maybe you could pass the df as an argument to avoid any mistakes.